# Where to create Entity objects in Spring Rest ? in service, DAO or API layer?

Tags: spring, architecture, spring-rest

I want to know where is the best layer to create my Entity Objects, for Example I have a model called Product, I've created and API post method with path ("/product") to create products, I was thinking to create an object of Product at the API method, and then pass this object to service layer to validate it and then in case of validation it will pass it to the DAO layer to persist it.

However I'm not sure if this a good practice, i'm thinking also about passing the Product parameters to the Service layer and creating it at the service layer instead of API layer.

I'm interested to hear your thoughts and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each layer should do some piece of work:

- API layer - validation
- Service layer - business logic of an application
- DAO layer - persisting to DB

I think that it's better to use DTO objects in API layer. For example, you can have a method like this:

```
class ProductController {
    public Response createProduce(@RequestBody @Valid ProductDto productDto) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the body of this method you can do some additional validation and call a service method:

```
class ProductService {
     public void createProduct(ProductDto productDto) {
         // impl
     }
}
```

In the body of a service method, you should create an entity object and map DTO to the newly created entity. Then you should call DAO layer.

In most cases, a service layer has to perform more operations than just calling a method from a DAO object. And operations should be performed in the same transaction, so, service layer should also manage transactions (I mean that `@Transactional` annotation should be present on service methods).

DAO object should only persist entity.

Answer (score 0):

I my experience you don't make entity objects in the API layer, instead you make Data Transfer Object (ProductDTO), wrapping all the entity properties received from the API call. This DTO class is used for any validation in the Service Layer and if everything goes well you make your Product entity instance only to persist through the DAO.